# How to define a nested member template outside a class template?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following class template:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
   void MyFunc();
};

template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::MyFunc()
{
  //...implementation goes here
}
```

I need to add another function template `MyFunc2` which accepts a template argument `T2`
i.e.,

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
   void MyFunc();

   template <class T2>
   static void MyFunc2(T2* data);
};

template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::MyFunc()
{
  //...implementation goes here
}

template <class T, class T2>
void MyClass<T>::MyFunc2(T2* pData)  // error here
{
  //...implementation goes here
}
```

I am using VS 2008 compiler. I am getting the error:

> error C2244: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

What should the function's definition and declaration look like in this case?

Comment: More often than not, it is easier to define the template member functions inlined in the class template definition to avoid all this small issues.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
template <class T>
template <class T2> 
void MyClass<T>::MyFunc2(T2* pData) 
{ 
  //...implementation goes here 
}
```

> $14.5.2/1 - "A template can be
> declared within a class or class
> template; such a template is called a
> member template. A member template can
> be defined within or outside its class
> definition or class template
> definition. **A member template of a
> class template that is defined outside
> of its class template definition shall
> be specified with the
> template-parameters of the class
> template followed by the
> template-parameters of the member
> template.**"

Comment: I've always found this syntax awkward, it doesn't get better with nested classes either...

Comment: @Chubsdad: how about the static keyword in the original templated member function declaration? Is it valid to drop it out in the implementation?

Answer (score 37):

What you're doing is fine, try this out:

```
template <typename S,typename T>
struct Structure
{
  S s ;
  T t ;

} ;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  Structure<int,double> ss ;
  ss.s = 200 ;
  ss.t = 5.4 ;

  return 1;
}
```

This code works.  If you're getting strange errors, see if you *forward declared* `Structure` using only 1 template parameter (that's what I was doing).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```
template <class T, class T2>
class MyClass
{
public:
    static void MyFunc2(T2* data);
};

template <class T, class T2>
void MyClass<T, T2>::MyFunc2(T2* pData)
{
    cout << "dummy " << *pData<< "\n";
}
```

Then

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    MyClass<int, int> a;
    int *b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 5;
    a.MyFunc2(b);
}
```

Output

```
Hello World!
dummy 5
```